# Wrong colors extracted from TBitmap.Palette

Tags: delphi, winapi, bitmap, delphi-xe5, palette

I am trying to extract colors from 8 bit bitmap with the usage of TBitmap.Palette. My colors are messed up and I don't know why. I've created a simple visual test to compare results:

[image]

Code that I am using:

```
procedure TForm36.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  LBitmap1, LBitmap2: TBitmap;
  LPaletteEntries: TMaxLogPalette;
  P1: PByteArray;
  P2: PRGBTriple;
  X,Y: Integer;
begin
  {$POINTERMATH ON}
  LBitmap1 := TBitmap.Create;
  LBitmap1.LoadFromFile('E:\3x2x8.bmp');
  img1.Picture.Assign(LBitmap1);

  LBitmap2 := TBitmap.Create;
  LBitmap2.Width := LBitmap1.Width;
  LBitmap2.Height := LBitmap1.Height;
  LBitmap2.PixelFormat := pf24bit;

  GetPaletteEntries(LBitmap1.Palette, 0, 256, LPaletteEntries);
  for Y := 0 to LBitmap1.Height - 1 do
  begin
    P1 := LBitmap1.ScanLine[Y];
    P2 := LBitmap2.ScanLine[Y];
    for X := 0 to LBitmap1.Width - 1 do
    begin
      P2[X].rgbtBlue := LPaletteEntries.palPalEntry[P1[X]].peBlue;
      P2[X].rgbtGreen := LPaletteEntries.palPalEntry[P1[X]].peGreen;
      P2[X].rgbtRed := LPaletteEntries.palPalEntry[P1[X]].peRed;
    end;
  end;
  img2.Picture.Assign(LBitmap2);
end;
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Please don't use JPG for non-photographic images.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand, Where do you see a JPG here?

Comment: @Kobik Here: `[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTsgF.jpg`, also clearly visible when looked at with magnifier. Especially when the discussion is about pixels and their colors, the jpg artifacts can throw off anybody trying to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @TomBrunberg, OK I see your point (and missed the screen-shot format completely). but I don't think it can affect anything in *this case*. the pallet  is *clearly* not the same.

Comment: Thank you for your input, I will use PNGs next time.

Answer (score 1):

I was passing a wrong structure to `GetPaletteEntries`. 
I should pass `palPalEntry: array [0..255] of TPaletteEntry;` and not `TMaxLogPalette`.